# can't access database values of django MultiSelectField in an external script

Tags: python, django, django-multiselectfield

I have a simple scenario where i have a django multiselectfield and the choices are:

```
jobs_multiple_choice = (
    (1, 'Social Media Manager'),
    (2, 'Online Tutor'),
    (3, 'Bookkeeper'),
    (4, 'Personal Trainer'),
    (5, 'Email Marketer'),
    (6, ' Freelance Writer'),
    (7, 'Website Designer'),
    (9, 'Instagram Influencer'),
    (8, 'SEO Expert '),
    (10, ' Facebook Ads Specialist '),
    (11, 'Graphic Designer'),
    (12, 'Voiceover Artist'),
    (30, 'Stock Photographer '),
    (62, 'Data Entry Worker'),
    )
```

i want to save number as an id of the jobs, now i want to get the data of the model into an external python script i did the usual import but i have an issue.
script.py:

```
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')
django.setup()

from practice.models import Jobs
a = Jobs.objects.all().first()
print(a.name)
```

the output its giving is representative value and not the number like ['1', '2', '42','4', '24'] etc but getting:
`Social Media Manager, Online Tutor, Bookkeeper, Personal Trainer, Email Marketer, Website Designer, Graphic Designer, Voiceover Artist, Data Entry Worker`
but! when i do that in manage.py shell, its giving me the desired value like below

```
>>> from practice.models import Jobs
>>> a = Jobs.objects.all().first()
>>> b = Jobs.objects.all().last()
>>> a.name
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '7', '11', '12', '62']
>>> b.name
['3', '4', '10', '11', '62']
>>>
```

how to i fix this and get the number value (btw i'll convert the list of string to list of int with list(map() function)
any help would be thankful!

Answer (score 0):

i just used list on to my a.name and it converted into list of string numbers, then i just used map(int, a) to make it a list of int and it worked.